# How do i deactivate "Your comment has been posted." after user posted a comment

Tags: hooks

How do I deactivate -Your comment has been posted- after user posted a comment.

Is it possible to deactivate the message above with out touching the core?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a custom submit handler to the comment form using [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if( $form_id == 'comment_form' ) { // find and use the actual form ID
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourmodule_your_custom_comment_submit_function';
  }
}
```

Then in that submit function check to see if the message exists using [drupal_get_messages()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_get_messages/7):

```
function yourmodule_your_custom_comment_submit_function(){
  $message = drupal_get_messages('status', false);
  if( $message['status'] == 'Your comment has been posted' ) { // Or what is the actual message
    drupal_get_messages('status');
  }
}
```

This is for Drupal 7 but these functions exists in older drupal versions. Check [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org) for details.

Comment: There are some problems with this. 1) `$message['status']` is an array, not a string, so the if-test will allways fail. 2) String may not be 'Your comment has been posted' if site's language is not English. 3) `drupal_get_messages('status')` will flush the entire status message queue, so any additional messages queued for display will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

For a no-code solution that disables all messages with specific language, install the [Disable Messages module](http://drupal.org/project/disable_messages), and under configuration you should enable filtering. Under "messages to be disabled" add

```
Your comment has been posted.
```

... or if your comment message differs, cut and paste your exact message into the field.

You can also use regular expressions or filter by user.